# Checking that a field in a List of Objects has a certain value?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, hashmap, contains

I have a list of `Person` Objects:

```
List<Person> allPersons = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

The Person object has a `field` called `Address`.

I would like to check that *at least one* Person in the list has a certain address
How can I do this?

I know that there is a [.containsValue()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/hashmap_containsvalue.htm) method when using a HashMap, but is there anything similar for an `ArrayList`?

Edit: please note that I am searching for a specific *field value* within each object, **not** the object itself?

Comment: `contains()` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)

Comment: Yes, a loop with if contains work.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ can you please give example

Comment: Do you also want to know *which* `Person` has a certain address ?

Comment: since java8 streams until that iterate the list

Comment: @Spotted no I don't care who has the address, just want to check that it is there in the list

Comment: Ok, so stick with Eran's solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to iterate over the List one way or another.

One convenient way to do it is with Java8 Streams :

```
boolean found = allPersons.stream().anyMatch(p->p.getAddress().equals(someAddress));
```

Comment: Thanks, what is the equivalent of this in order version of Java?

Comment: @java123999 In an older version you'll have to iterate over the list with a loop (for example `boolean found=false; for (Person p : allPersons()) {if (p.getAddress().equals(someAddress)) {found = true;break;}}`

Comment: @java123999 Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481346/finding-out-if-a-list-of-objects-contains-something-with-a-specified-field-value

Answer (score 3):

You can use `asLazy()` and `collect()` from [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/):

If you can use the [MutableList](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/7.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/list/MutableList.html) interface:

```
MutableList<Person> allPersons = Lists.mutable.empty();
boolean found =
    allPersons.asLazy().collect(Person::getAddress).contains(someAddress);
```

If you can't change the type of allPersons from `List`:

```
List<Person> allPersons = new ArrayList<>();
boolean found = 
    LazyIterate.collect(allPersons, Person::getAddress).contains(someAddress);
```

Note: I am a contributor to Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 2):

If you plan on making this check often, load the addresses in the `Set<String>` on which you can then call the `contains` method:

```
Set<String> allAddresses = 
   allPersons.stream().map(Person::getAddress).collect(toSet());
// ...
boolean found = allAddresses.contains(someAddress);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could simply do while + iterator loop

```
boolean found = false;
Iterator it = allPersons.iterator();
Person currentPerson = null;

while(!found && it.hasNext()){
    currentPerson = it.next();
    if(currentPerson != null && paramAdress.equals(person.getAddress()){
        found = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

As a complement, if you don't feel comfortable with Eran's answer (which is the best possible answer) or you can't use Java 8, just create a method like:

```
public boolean checkAdress(String adress)
{
    boolean found = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < allPersons.size() && !found; i++)
        found = allPersons.get(i).getAdress().equals(adress);
    return found;
}
```

This is what I used to do before Java 8.

Comment: The loop exits if found is true. Look at the condition inside the for. And no, I do not HAVE to use the iteration notation. It isn't more efficient.

Comment: My bad! Haven't realized your loop exits at the right time! :-) That said, even if it is not more efficient in the case of an `ArrayList`, the for-each loop is much more readable.

Comment: Yeha, but the thing here is that modern programming uses the concept of "flow". This is why we don't use "break", "continue" and "GOTO" anymore (or as often). If he uses the for-each loop, he'll have to place 2 return lines in the method. It isn't good to teach noobies those practices.

Comment: <ot> From experience, having more than one `return` in a method is usually not harmful to the design or understanding of the code, except maybe for languages that don't have garbage collection. </ot> Besides, a for-each loop is more understandable and less error-prone than a loop manipulating indexes, especially for beginners.

Comment: Haha, let's agree to disagree. Anyway, good practices are very subjective and I'm just repeating after my professor.