# Add item only once in custom ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I've made my own custom ArrayList like this:

```
public class Points {
    String hoodName;
    Double points;
    Integer hoodId;
    public Points(String hN, Double p, Integer hI){
        hoodName = hN;
        points =p;
        hoodId = hI;
    }

    public Double getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    public Integer getHoodId() {
        return hoodId;
    }

    public String getHoodName() {
        return hoodName;
    }
}
```

When I'm adding data from my JSON api it adds item multiple times. I've tried this code to add the items only once it:

```
if (!points.contains(jsonObject.getString("hood_name"))) {
                                    points.add(new Points(jsonObject.getString("hood_name"), jsonObject.getDouble("points"), jsonObject.getInt("hood_id")));
                                }
```

If also tried this:

```
if (!points.contains(Points(jsonObject.getString("hood_name"), jsonObject.getDouble("points"), jsonObject.getInt("hood_id")))) {
                                    points.add(new Points(jsonObject.getString("hood_name"), jsonObject.getDouble("points"), jsonObject.getInt("hood_id")));
                                }
```

This code is working when I use a ArrayList or `ArrayList<Integer>` but not when I'm using `ArrayList<Points>`

Can anyone explain me how I can avoid duplication in my list?

Comment: hoodName is just one property in your list, you can't check contain with one property of your object, create `Points` object, override equals method in `Points` then your code will be worked

Comment: Also, looking at your code, seems like the sequence of Point is not important? In that case, using a Map or HashMap may be better.

Comment: @tingyik90 No the sequence is not important

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding out if a list of Objects contains something with a specified field value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481346/finding-out-if-a-list-of-objects-contains-something-with-a-specified-field-value)

Comment: Do something similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7481383/1479511)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comments that Order doesn't matter , I would have an `HashSet<String>` to store and check the `hood_name`and If you want to get `object` by entering `hood_name` you can use `HashMap<String,Point` instead which returns the object in `O(1)` time.

So You need to create a `HashSet<String>` which will keep track of `hood_name` of all objects present in the `ArrayList<Points>`.

```
HashSet<String> all_ids=new HashSet<String>();

if (!all_ids.contains(jsonObject.getString("hood_name"))) 
{
    points.add(new Points(jsonObject.getString("hood_name"), jsonObject.getDouble("points"), jsonObject.getInt("hood_id")));
    all_ids.add(jsonObject.getString("hood_name")); //You need to add it to set as Now it exists in the list.                     
}
```

Further more , If you want to only use `ArrayList<Point>` to execute this task , You can override `equals(Object E)` and `hashCode()` methods in `Point` class. For more information , refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322129/arraylists-custom-contains-method).

Comment: Aw.. you beat me to it.. :(

Answer (score 1):

If the sequence is not important, then you can use a `HashMap` to uniquely identify them.

```
HashMap<String, Point> pointMap = new HashMap<>();
String hoodName = jsonObject.getString("hood_name");
Point point = new Point(jsonObject.getString("hood_name"),
                  jsonObject.getDouble("points"),
                  jsonObject.getInt("hood_id"))
if (!points.containsKey(hoodName)) pointMap.put(hoodName, point);
```

In fact, if you will always want to overwrite the old point with new point which has the same `hoodName`, you do not need to check whether the `Point` exists in your list. Calling `pointMap.put(key, object)` will always replace the object with the same key.

Answer (score 1):

In this case the Points object use default `equals()` method which is inconsistent. As you want to use `contains` method, you should implement `equals()` method like this way.

```
public class Points {

    String hoodName;
    Double points;
    Integer hoodId;

    public Points(String hN, Double p, Integer hI) {
        hoodName = hN;
        points = p;
        hoodId = hI;
    }

    public Double getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    public Integer getHoodId() {
        return hoodId;
    }

    public String getHoodName() {
        return hoodName;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof Points)) {
            return false;
        }
        Points points = (Points) obj;

        return points.getHoodName().equals(getHoodName().trim()) &&
                points.getHoodId() == getHoodId()
                && points.getPoints() == getPoints();


      }

    }
```

If you `ovverride` `equals()` method, you can easily use it in `ArrayList<Points>`. Hope it will work in your case.